# SIM808 Error 601 Network Error

Tags: at-command, cellular-network, adafruit

I am using the SIM808 module with a sim card on the Ting network. I keep getting the 601 error when trying to post data to a website. What am I doing wrong. The AT commands I am sending are below responses begin with >

```
AT+CREG?
>+CREG: 0,1
>OK
AT+CIPSHUT
>SHUT OK
AT+CGATT=1
>OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
>OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","wholesale"
>OK
AT+CSTT="wholesale"
>OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1
>OK
AT+CIICR
>OK
AT+SAPBR=2,1
>+SAPBR: 1,1,"162.168.167.120"
>OK

AT+HTTPINIT
>OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
>OK
AT+HTTPPARA="UA","SIMCom_MODULE"
>OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://posttestserver.com/post.php"
>OK
AT+HTTPPARA="REDIR",1
>OK
AT+HTTPSSL=1
>OK
AT+HTTPDATA=22, 10000
>DOWNLOAD
-->this is post data<--
>OK
AT+HTTPACTION=1
>OK
>+HTTPACTION: 1,601,0
AT+HTTPREAD
>OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:) sim should be activated for data.
2:) if apn has password and username they also should be passed before using

```
    at+sapbr=1,1
```

3:) if required before at+sapbr commands the first command try

```
    at+sapbr=0,1 
to de-activate bearer profile.
```

Answer (score 2):

Working on a similar device, SIM868, on Vodafone Ireland network and I kept getting a 601 error returned when attempting comms with a development test server.
I added a proxy server and port to the APN settings before sending data which  returned 503 - service unavailable.
Commands used:

- AT+HTTPPARA="PROIP","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
- AT+HTTPPARA="PROPORT","xxxxx"

I put them after:

- AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1'
- AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx"

Some APN settings have different proxy servers/ports for different services depending on provider, e.g. GPRS, WAP, MMS, 3G, 4G

I have successfully comm'ed with httpbin.org using HTTP POST (as opposed to HTTPS, my chip doesn't support it) **without** the proxy settings included. Your code up until the HTTPACTION return looks good, pretty much the same layout I used to comm with httpbin.org.

*Edit: SIM868 does support ssl, according to the supplier. Not sure what version*

Not a fix but might get you or someone else a little closer to successful comms with these modems (documentation is a little sparse around certain topics)

*Edit: Turned out to be a server side problem, didn't need the proxy settings. Added the AT command list which successfully talked to httpbin.org*

```
AT
OK

AT+CMEE=2
OK

AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY

OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,1

OK

AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 1

OK

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 13,0

OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","live.vodafone.com"
OK

AT+SAPBR=1,1
OK

AT+SAPBR=2,1
+SAPBR: 1,1,"10.231.208.96"

OK

AT+HTTPINIT
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://httpbin.org/post"
OK

AT+HTTPDATA=16,10000
DOWNLOAD


OK

AT+HTTPACTION=1
OK

+HTTPACTION: 1,200,326

AT+HTTPREAD
+HTTPREAD: 326
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "SIM868 GPRS test",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "16",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "SIMCOM_MODULE"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "213.233.150.18",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}

OK

AT+HTTPTERM
OK

AT+SAPBR=0,1
```